# JQuery Hover Method within a Scroll Method

Tags: jquery, scroll, hover

I am attempting to mimic the navbar that is seen on [this site](https://www.allbirds.com/), but am having some trouble with the JQuery. I am using an if statement for the scroll formatting and then include a hover method in the bottom of the if statement.

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 100) {
  $("nav").css("background-color","white");
  $("nav").css("height","75px");
  $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css("color","black");
  $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a").css("color","black");
} 
else {
  $("nav").css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
  $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css("color","white");
  $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a").css("color","white");
  $("nav").css("height","125px");
  $("nav").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
  });
 }  
});
});
```

The issue with the current code I have is that the hover method is changing the navbar after I scroll to be transparent when I would like it to not change and stay white.

Answer (score 1):

You use too much JavaScript. You should let CSS style your elements. Instead of using multiple times `.css`, you should simply add a class to the `nav` then style based on that.

The `.hover` part can also be done in CSS. Rule of thumbs, you should never ever attach event handler inside an other event handler; there is always a better way.

In the end, you should have something like this :

*Disclaimer, I did not style like you did, nor used your HTML, so you should adapt this code to your needs.*

```js
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
      $("nav").toggleClass("sticked", scroll >= 100);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height : 300vh;
}

nav{
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  width : 100%;
  height : 125px;
  background : transparent;
  }
  
  nav .text{
    color : black;
  }
  
  nav:hover{
    background: red;
    }
    
    nav:hover .text{
      color : white;
    }
  
  nav.sticked{
    background : red;
    height : 75px;
    }
    
    nav.sticked .text{
      color : white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<span class="text">text here</span>
</nav>
```